# What would be the best way to mine Twitter data?

Tags: php, python, r, twitter, data-mining

I need to do a MASSIVE data mine. I want to find out;

1. A users location
2. Look at their tweets for specific words in the last two days
3. Repeat (ideally) for every twitter user

I've seen R recommended somewhere, but wouldn't really know where to begin.

Happy with CSV, json or SQL endpoint.

Comment: http://www.r-bloggers.com/search/twitter

Comment: You need to do a MASSIVE internet search. Like, the first hit on Google. Oh, and you need to read the FAQ on what is a good question (because this isn't - it's a "I'm too lazy to google, so I instead write a request here" question)

Comment: I did research it, but I have very little experience with R or python so even what I found was too advanced for me to implement.

Answer (score 1):

As you tagged "python" in your question, I'm going to assume you're ok with it ! Twitter lets you access its data by two APIs :

- REST API allows you to make specific user requests (profile, friends, etc.), but it only allows a few queries per hour, so it probably does not meet your "massive data" criterion
- The streaming API delivers tweets based on a search on real-time. You can definitely harvest massive data using this API, and if I remember correctly, tweets come up with useful infos (user who tweeted of course, but probably location too if enabled).

Tweepy (http://www.tweepy.org/) is a user-friendly Python library implementing both Twitter APIs, providing particularly helpful functions for capturing data from the streaming API (see examples here : https://github.com/tweepy/examples).